# Mocking a bad request response from an Ionic / Angular application

Tags: angular, rest, ionic-framework

I am trying to create error handling for my api requests from the frontend but not sure how I would go about mocking different status codes e.g 500, 504. I am using Ionic w/ Angular.

I have tried using `http://httpstat.us/` by changing out the request url to `httpstat.us/504` but it seems to prefix the request url with my own localhost address. I.e `Request URL: http://localhost:8100/httpstat.us/504` which returns a 404. I am assuming it has something to do with the framework which assumes I am requesting from a local backend? When prefixing with `http://httpstat.us/504` I only receive 200 OK status codes regardless of what parameters I use.

Is there any other way to mock a response using the Angular HTTP module to mock bad requests? Or anyone know how to remove the localhost prefix from the request url when using a url that does not have http:// or https:// ?

Answer (score 1):

See if `npm start` has a `--proxy-config`, it could be that `proxy-config` that is adding the `localhost:8100`. If it is, then it will be difficult to remove it just for one API call because I assume you need other API calls to go to this API call.

Another place where the URL could be set is an HTTP Interceptor, see if your application has any of those and see what they do.

If I were you, I would use `Fiddler Everywhere` to mock the response status and body. Check this quick [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbQ-n4CmD9I) out about `Fiddler Everywhere`. You can download it [here](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler-everywhere) and you can watch more videos on the subject.

To summarize, in the video I have linked, pay close attention at 2:45 where he mocks a response for a URL with `auto-responder`. You can set the status there and once you modify the response, every time you make a request, it will respond with this mock.